# Regex: can't understand the endpos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could you help me understand why `print(truth(prog.match(text, 0, 6)))` equals true?

```
import re
from operator import truth

prog = re.compile(r'<HTML>$')
text = "<HTML>            "
print("Last symbol: {}".format(len('<HTML>')-1))
print(truth(prog.match(text, 0, 6)))
print(truth(prog.match(text)))
```

Comment: What is `truth`? Did you mean `bool`?

Comment: `truth` is not a built-in: either there is code missing or this does not equal `True`...

Comment: @brianpck Oops.

Comment: Hope this link will be helped to you
https://www.dotnetperls.com/if-python

Comment: Edited the code. Pardon for the "truth".

Comment: @Michael `operator.truth` is equivalent to the built-in `bool`, which everyone instantly understands and doesn't require an import. I would suggest using that in the future :)

Comment: @orlp Asking the hard questions.  What *is* truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `match(text, startpos, endpos)` method of a compiled regex, it will act as if you've passed `match(text[startpos:endpos])` (well, [not exactly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.search), but for the purposes of `$`, it is). This means that it'll think `<HTML>` is at the end of the input (which is what `$` matches).

However, when this is not the case the extra whitespace at the end of `text` will prevent `$` from matching, so no match is found.

Comment: Hm, it explains the situation well. This feature is not documented, is it?

Comment: @Michael [It is](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match).

Comment: In the documentation: pos and endpos parameters limit the search region. I would say that it is not written that it works like slicing. By the way, if it worked like slicing, couldn''t we see the same effect with the beginning? text = " <HTML>            "
print(truth(prog.match(text, 1)))

Comment: @Michael The documentation covers `^` as well.

Comment: Have you trued it with r'^<HTML>', text = " <HTML>" and pos=1?

Comment: @Michael _"The optional second parameter pos gives an index in the string where the search is to start; it defaults to 0. This is not completely equivalent to slicing the string; the '^' pattern character matches at the real beginning of the string and at positions just after a newline, but not necessarily at the index where the search is to start."_